# Pandas - groupby ints that are contigous

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a df that looks like this:

```
   some_int   another_int
0      1           5
1      2           6  
2      10          7
3      11          8
4      15          9
```

So I want to perform a groupby operation on those elements that have a diff of only 1 between each other. Let's say I want to groupby some_int (diff of 1) and perform a sum on another_int By doing that I would obtain something like:

```
   some_int   another_int
0      1           5
1      2           6  
2      10          7
3      11          8
4      15          9
```

```
           sum
0      5 + 6 = 11     
1      7 + 8 = 15  
2       15 = 15
```

What is the best pythonic way to do so? I tried creating a diff mask then shift it and perform or amongst those. However, it seems kind of verbose. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest making a new column called `group`

```
df['group'] = (df.some_int.diff() > 1).cumsum()
```

then you can `groupby` this column and apply a custom function that returns the sum of `another_int` or the single values in `some_int`:

```
def sum_or_val(x):
    print(len(x))
    if len(x) > 1:
        return sum(x['another_int'])
    return x['some_int'].values[0]
grouped = df.groupby('group').apply(sum_or_val)
```